# Python not detecting module

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a really simple stupid problem but i'm quite new to python and need some guidance.

i'm trying to import a key board module with:

```
import keyboard
```

however i'm getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

i've double checked the install and it's definitely there. i used

```
pip install keyboard
```

pls help

Comment: Can you include the output of `pip --version`, `python --version`, and `whereis python` (if you're using Mac/Linux) or `where python` for Windows

Comment: just check whether you create any virtual environment? if you a working on virtual environment, but you installed the package in open environment, you wont get this package in your program

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.x

Using:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check where Python is looking for packages, and check those locations to see if you find your `keyboard` module

```sh
$ python3 -c "import sys; from pprint import pprint; pprint(sys.path)"
```

2. Enable Pip's verbose logging mode to see what it's doing behind the scenes

```sh
$ pip install keyboard -vvvvv
```

3. Check to see if Pip thinks that `keyboard` is installed

```sh
$ pip list | grep keyboard
# or,
$ pip show keyboard
```

4. Use Pip as a module

```sh
python3 -m pip install keyboard
```

One of these is bound to help.